# Lookup Formula with Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-2003

In my EXCEL book have a table:

[image]

How can I find a name by two values Text1+Text2?
So in my case I want to get in result: `Jane` if I write `AA12345`
I try to do this by this formula:

`=INDEX(A1:D3;MATCH(W1;A1:A3&B1:B3;0);)`

[image]

I need to do something like this:
http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/lookupfunction1/ss/2011-03-03-excel-2010-vlookup-multiple-values-sbs-tutorial.htm
but in my case in 2003 EXCEl I have an error and this example is not working

Comment: The formula in that format is `{=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(W1,A:A&B:B,0),0)}` assuming cell W1 = "AA12345".

Comment: In this case I have value error

Comment: Change ALL column references from eg A:A to A1:A65536 or whatever row limit you want

Comment: Probably best not to use 65536 in Excel 2003 as it wasn't optimized for large ranges back then. This will use first 100 rows `{=INDEX(C1:C100,MATCH(W1,A1:A100&B1:B100,0),0)}`

Comment: Perhaps you should spend some time and read the tutorial :)

Comment: @ooo Note that A1:A65536 = A:A - you can't use either in "array formulas" in Excel 2003

Comment: @barryhoudini - your right. It's been a few years since I last used 2003 but I remember the dreaded .rows.Count -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a bug in Excel 2003?

[image]

And the formulae (which are both Array CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER)

[image]

Comment: in my version I try this formula: =ИНДЕКС(C1:C100;ПОИСКПОЗ(H10&I10;A1:A100&B1:B100;0);0)

Comment: that is the same as =INDEX(C1:C100;MATCH(H10&I10;A1:A100&B1:B100;0);0)

Comment: Works fine here. Do the values actually match in cells H10 & I10? Try matching the cell lookups with the values in the list eg `=H10=A2` and if it shows FALSE then the values are different. Could be extra padding such as spaces etc

Comment: I have update my question with an example

Comment: Are you entering the formula by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to make it an array formula? You can't just press ENTER or it will give #VALUE!

Comment: after pressing enter I have this value error

Comment: Don't press ENTER!!! Hold down CTRL then hold down SHIFT then press ENTER - CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: So can you explain me what was the problem and why it was not working before?

Comment: Effectively your working with arrays of values rather than a single value. This link will explain much more than I can fit in a comment. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the two columns and apply the same formula over the concatenated value. Click [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/concat.php) for more info about the function concatenate.

Comment: so, what is a correct formula?

Comment: @revolutionkpi - "You can concatenate the two columns and `apply the same formula` over the concatenated value."

Comment: I need to  have separate columns

Comment: Assume your example is in columns A,B,C & D. In column E have `=A2&B2` then to find AA12345 the new formula will be `=INDEX(C:C,MATCH("AA12345",E:E,0),1)` replacing "AA12345" with whatever cell holds the lookup value

Comment: I will not create additional columns or rows, my question is how to make the sequential search

Comment: You could use an array formula but I'd advise against it if you intend to have this in more than 1 cell. `{=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1, ("AA"=A:A) * (12345=B:B), 0),1)}`